# Excel formula related to conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

*Column A* has 10 numbers expressed as percentages and is conditionally formatted to highlight the top 40%.

I want *column B* to show a "1" next to the corresponding highlighted top 40% of numbers in *column A*.

I think, I need to use an "IF" statement, but don't know a formula that includes "Top 40%" etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this in column B

```
=IF(A1>=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$10,0.4),1,0)
```

Depending on your specific data, you may need `>=` or just `>` - you can determine that when working with the data.

Comment: Make `0.4` be `40%` and enter that in any other cell, then add the cell reference with `$` as in $COL$ROW in the formula - this allows to set the "top percentage" for all cells in one go.